# Adding custom labels to pytorch dataloader/dataset does not work for custom dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am working on the cactus image competition on Kaggle and I am trying to use the PyTorch dataloader for my CNN. However, I am running into an issue where I cannot set the labels for the training set. The training set images are given in a folder and the labels are in a csv file. This is my code.

```
 train = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root='../input/train', 
 transform=transform)

 train.targets = torch.from_numpy(df['has_cactus'].values)

 train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

 for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
     print(data[1])
```

This code outputs batch tensors of all zeros, which is clearly incorrect as the great majority of the labels(if you were to look at the dataframe) are ones. I believe that this is a problem with assigning the labels to "train.targets". If "train.targets" is printed prior to the assignment of the other labels, it returns a tensor of all zeros which is consistent with the incorrect results that I am getting. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 8):

I typically inherit the builtin DataSet class as follows:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
class DataSet:

    def __init__(self, root):
        """Init function should not do any heavy lifting, but
            must initialize how many items are available in this data set.
        """

        self.ROOT = root
        self.images = read_images(root + "/images")
        self.labels = read_labels(root + "/labels")

    def __len__(self):
        """return number of points in our dataset"""

        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """ Here we have to return the item requested by `idx`
            The PyTorch DataLoader class will use this method to make an iterable for
            our training or validation loop.
        """

        img = images[idx]
        label = labels[idx]

        return img, label
```

And now, you can create an instance of this class as,

```
ds = Dataset('../input/train')
```

Now, you can instantiate the DataLoader:

```
dl = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False, num_workers=4, drop_last=True)
```

This will create batches of your data that you can access as:

```
for image, label in dl:
    print(label)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would you recommend that I implement the "read_images" method in my code?

Comment: @LeoStepanewk is this another question?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom dataset loader by inheriting the builtin `Dataset` class as @Sai Krishnan mentioned.

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image

VOC_CLASSES = ('background',  # always index 0
               'aeroplane', 'bicycle', 'bird', 'boat',
               'bottle', 'bus', 'car', 'cat', 'chair',
               'cow', 'diningtable', 'dog', 'horse',
               'motorbike', 'person', 'pottedplant',
               'sheep', 'sofa', 'train', 'tvmonitor')

NUM_CLASSES = len(VOC_CLASSES) + 1

class customDataset(Dataset):
    """Pascal VOC 2007 Dataset"""
    def __init__(self, list_file, img_dir, mask_dir, transform=None):
        # list of images to load in a .txt file
        self.images = open(list_file, "rt").read().split("\n")[:-1]
        self.transform = transform
        # note that in the .txt file the image names are stored without the extension(.jpg or .png)
        self.img_extension = ".jpg"
        self.mask_extension = ".png"

        self.image_root_dir = img_dir
        self.mask_root_dir = mask_dir
        # can comment the line below
        self.counts = self.__compute_class_probability()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        name = self.images[index]
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_root_dir, name + self.img_extension)
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.mask_root_dir, name + self.mask_extension)

        image = self.load_image(path=image_path)
        gt_mask = self.load_mask(path=mask_path)
        data = {
                    'image': torch.FloatTensor(image),
                    'mask' : torch.LongTensor(gt_mask)
                    }
        return data

    def __compute_class_probability(self):
        counts = dict((i, 0) for i in range(NUM_CLASSES))

        for name in self.images:
            mask_path = os.path.join(self.mask_root_dir, name + self.mask_extension)

            raw_image = Image.open(mask_path).resize((224, 224))
            imx_t = np.array(raw_image).reshape(224*224)
            imx_t[imx_t==255] = len(VOC_CLASSES)

            for i in range(NUM_CLASSES):
                counts[i] += np.sum(imx_t == i)
        return counts

    def get_class_probability(self):
        values = np.array(list(self.counts.values()))
        p_values = values/np.sum(values)
        return torch.Tensor(p_values)

    def load_image(self, path=None):
        # can use any other library too like OpenCV as long as you are consistent with it
        raw_image = Image.open(path)
        raw_image = np.transpose(raw_image.resize((224, 224)), (2,1,0))
        imx_t = np.array(raw_image, dtype=np.float32)/255.0

        return imx_t
    # can comment the below function if not needed
    def load_mask(self, path=None):
        raw_image = Image.open(path)
        raw_image = raw_image.resize((224, 224))
        imx_t = np.array(raw_image)
        imx_t[imx_t==255] = len(VOC_CLASSES)
        return imx_t
```

Once the class is ready you can create an instance of it and use it.

```
data_root = os.path.join("VOCdevkit", "VOC2007")
list_file_path = os.path.join(data_root, "ImageSets", "Segmentation", "train.txt")
img_dir = os.path.join(data_root, "JPEGImages")
mask_dir = os.path.join(data_root, "SegmentationClass")


objects_dataset = customDataset(list_file=list_file_path,
                                        img_dir=img_dir,
                                        mask_dir=mask_dir)
sample = objects_dataset[k]
image, mask = sample['image'], sample['mask']
image.transpose_(0, 2)

fig = plt.figure()

a = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(image)

a = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(mask)

plt.show()
```

Please make sure that you insert the file paths properly. Also you will have to load the labels properly in the `customDataset()` class.

Note: This snippet is just an example of how a custom dataloader should be. You will have to make appropriate changes in it to make it work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned you have to implement a custom dataset as it is important to make `__getitem__` return the sample and its label. Otherwise the DataLoader can not figure out the labels by itself.

I also recommend PyTorch documentation about [Creating a Custom Dataset for your files](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#creating-a-custom-dataset-for-your-files) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXOzkkB5eH0) YouTube video.